# mapping jooq record entity to pojo with nested objects

Tags: java, jooq, pojo, one-to-one

i have two tables d_cities, d_countries. Mapping between them is unidirectional like this:

[image: relation]

also, i have two pojo dtos like this:

[image: relation between dto]

Entity classes are jooq generated.

Now I can't come up with the decision how can I retrieve response like this when i call getCityById(String cityId):

[image: cityDto]

Can you please help me with this problem? I am very new to JOOQ and DSLContext methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways of nesting records in jOOQ:

#### Directly in SQL

[jOOQ supports SQL nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/) just like standard SQL and some implementations (e.g. PostgreSQL). If it's not supported natively by your RDBMS, then jOOQ will emulate it. You can attach [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) to your nested record expressions in order to map them to your custom `CountryDto` type as follows:

```java
List<CityDto> result =
ctx.select(
      CITY.ID,
      CITY.NAME,
      row(CITY.country().ID, CITY.country().NAME).mapping(CountryDto::new))
   .from(CITY)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(CityDto::new));
```

This assumes you have appropriate constructors on your DTOs. I guess you'll have to add a lombok `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation for that purpose (I really recommend it, it will work very well with jOOQ's [ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)!)

For convenience, I'm using [implicit path joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), but you can obviously use explicit joins as well.

#### Using `DefaultRecordMapper` functionality

The [reflection based, historic `DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) can nest records as well using a dot notation, if that's more your style. Just write this:

```java
List<CityDto> result =
ctx.select(
      CITY.ID,
      CITY.NAME,
      CITY.country().ID.as("countryDto.id"), 
      CITY.country().NAME.as("countryDto.name"))
   .from(CITY)
   .fetchInto(CityDto.class);
```

As this is purely reflection based, there's no type safety. As soon as you rename your properties in your DTO, the query will stop working. Personally, I recommend the explicit, type safe approach from the first solution for that reason, specifically, because it can also work with [nested collections](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/).

Comment: what if i want to retrieve one record, not list of records?return dsl.select(city.ID, city.NAME, city.dCountries().ID.as("countryDto.id"),
              city.dCountries().NAME.as("countryDto.name")).from(city).where(city.ID.eq(cityId)).fetchOne(); doesnt work

Comment: can you please look at it? @Lukas

Comment: @GazizBakyt Use `fetchOneInto(Class)`